# What is the proper way in getting data from a json file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

What is the proper way in getting a data from my json file? the result is always undefined

Item name: undefined
Item key: undefined

**.json file**

```
[{"item_id":"1","item_name":"Book","item_key":"290Q12"}]
```

**my script, jquery**

```
var item_name;
var item_key;
var item_id = '<?php echo $row->item_id; ?>';
var get_loc = '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/main/get_one_item_info/';

item();
function item() {
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'GET', 
        url:  get_loc + item_id, 
        data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
        success: function (data) { 
         for (var i=0;i<data.length;++i)
         {
            item_name = data[0].item_name;
            item_key = data[0].item_key;
            document.getElementById("items").innerHTML = "Item name: " + item_name + "<br>Item key: " + item_key + " ";   
         }
        }
    });
});
setTimeout(item, 2500);
};
```

**index.php**

```
<div id='items'></div>
```

Comment: its `$row[0]->item_id`, there's another dimension inside, and its an invalid `JSON` string `"item_key":"290Q12}]` missing closing `"`

Comment: Did you set data type to be JSON in `.ajax`?

Comment: it has " .. sorry typo error

Comment: question updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try this

```
    $url = 'your url';
    $obj = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
    $item_name = $obj['item_name'];
    $item_key = $obj['item_key'];
   // print_r($obj);
```

Comment: i want to store item_name and item_key in a variable before i will output it

Answer (score 1):

You can use $.getJSON() method with the file name mentioned on it....

```
$.getJSON('link of json file',function(response){
// action to be performed
});
```